# Android studio waiting for target device to come online timeout

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-studio-3.0

I'm using android studio ver 3.1.4. I'm deploying using nexus 5x api q virtual device. Everything seems fine from gradling too installing. But the problem is  "waiting for target device is online". The virtual device is already running, but it keeps showing "waiting for target device is online" and ending up with " Time out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online". I haven't found any solution yet. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can disable and re-enable adb server like this

```
  adb kill-server
  adb forward --remove-all
  adb start-server
```

You need also to check if **Android Emulator** is checked under SDK Tools.

Comment: i've checked my android emulator and it's installed. still the same

Comment: @YudhaPratama Try unchecking and checking **Android Emulator** again. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar issue that comes up about once a month for me.
I went to:

**Open AVD Manager** --> **Right Click** --> **Wipe Data**

After that, retry to load the emulator and it should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, although its not a proper solution, *Invalidate Caches and Restart* solves the problem for my case

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete this device then re-install. Don't forget to clear caches.